# How to keep x-axis max value not changed in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

series.addPoint (Object options, [Boolean redraw], [Boolean shift], [Mixed animation])

```
      chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, false, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                maxPadding: 1
            }
```

I want to dynamically update data in a fix x-axis range such as 9:00 to 18:00,but when redrawing happened,the max value in x-axis will increase,how can i keep the value not changed?Just like a stock chart dynamically show the stock price.

(http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=FB+Interactive#symbol=fb;range=1d;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;)

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/cruelcage/ny43Z/

can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell highcharts what the min and max values to plot on the y-axis:

```
 yAxis: {
            min:0,
            max:1,
```

See the updated example http://jsfiddle.net/2ghdH/.

Yoo can do the same on the x-axis as well:

```
var end = (new Date()).getTime()+100000;

 xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxPadding :1.5,
            max:end
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nV8cu/